# Google Drive Sheets запрос

Tags: java, android, google-drive

Не могу понять, как сделать запрос всех колонок в документе, используя Google Drive API. В [руководстве](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/1PtiSLIP70hTB8yTp90ciyOVKzWXqqH1d7x-3s2cTdLg/values/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8) я посмотрел пример запроса и попытался сформировать свой.

У меня есть [документ](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PtiSLIP70hTB8yTp90ciyOVKzWXqqH1d7x-3s2cTdLg/edit#gid=1180689210) и у него я пытаюсь запросить страницу "Задачи" (т.е. все ее колонки). Получился вот такой вот запрос:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1PtiSLIP70hTB8yTp90ciyOVKzWXqqH1d7x-3s2cTdLg/values/Задачи
```

Вот так я пытаюсь его выполнить (такая реализация потока — только на первое время):

```
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        URL sheetUrl = new URL("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1PtiSLIP70hTB8yTp90ciyOVKzWXqqH1d7x-3s2cTdLg/values/Задачи");
        HttpURLConnection sheetConnection = (HttpURLConnection) sheetUrl.openConnection();

        if (sheetConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sheetConnection.getInputStream()));

            String responce = "";
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                responce += inputLine;

            in.close();

            Log.i(TAG, "responce = " + responce);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Ответа нет");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}).start();
```

И в лог мне выводит "ответа нет".

---

В чем моя ошибка и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы, не пройдя процедуру **авторизации**, пытаетесь выполнить запрос, и метод:

```
sheetConnection.getResponseCode()
```

возвращает `403`, а весь возвращаемый на Ваш запрос `JSON` выглядит так:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request cannot be identified with a client project. Please pass a valid API key with the request.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Подробнее про авторизацию и ключи доступа можете почитать по ссылке: [Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing).

Comment: @bukashka101, Даже если Ваш файл виден всем (`public`), то для доступа к нему посредством API, нужен `API key`. Из браузера Вы его можете видеть, потому что Вы залогинены. Я пробовал перейти (в браузере) по указанной Вами ссылке – в ответ получаю вышеприведенный `JSON`.